# Xamrin.Forms AWSSDK.S3 cannot be compiled to physical iOS Device

Tags: amazon-s3, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, aws-sdk

The sdk works fine on iOS simulators, however, when I try to test it on physical iOS Devices, it always fails in compilation and throws me this error:

Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Net.IWebProxy', referenced from the method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient Amazon.S3.AmazonS3HttpUtil::GetHttpClient(Amazon.Runtime.IClientConfig)' in 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral (MT2101)

I am using Xamarin.Forms, the version of AWSSDK.Core is 3.3.21.14 and S3 is .3.17.

Is there any solution that I don't need to roll back to the old version? Thanks.

Comment: [https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/884](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/884) may help you.

Comment: That's me too, lol. But I am still looking for a better solution, anyway thank you; )

Comment: Did you ever solved this ?